# How to change value for 'options' and 'select' in wp_dropdown_categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, custom-taxonomy

I am currently using this code to display only the child terms of the current category being viewed -

```
<?php

//first get the current term
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

//then set the args for wp_dropdown_categories
 $args = array(
    'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth'  => 2,
    'title_li' => '',
        'show_option_all' => All,
        'hide_if_empty' => true
    );
 wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
?>
```

I need to be able to add values and classes to the 's and the opening . How can I modify the above code to do so?

Im not sure but I think Im getting close. -

```
<?php
function get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args){
//first get the current term
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );
 $args = array(
    'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth'  => 2,
    'title_li' => '',
        'show_option_all' => All,
        'hide_if_empty' => true
    );
    $output ="<select name='".$term_slug."'><option selected='".$selected."' value='".$emptyvalue."'>Select a Category</option>'";

    foreach($current_term as $term){
        $output .="<option name='".$term_slug."' value='".$link."'>".$term_name."</option>";
    }
    $output .="</select>";
return $output;
}
echo get_terms_dropdown($taxonomies, $args);

?>
```

The problem is the drop down is not showing any categories/terms, what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok yet I answered another one of my own questions. I was able to create the drop down filter that retrieves the child terms of the current taxonomy page being viewed. For anyone interested in the solution, here it is ---

First I had to create in my functions.php file a walker class --

```
class SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown extends Walker_CategoryDropdown{

    function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args) {
        $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 2);
        $cat_name = apply_filters('list_cats', $category->name, $category);

        if( !isset($args['value']) ){
            $args['value'] = ( $category->taxonomy != 'category' ? 'slug' : 'id' );
        }

        $value = ($args['value']=='slug' ? $category->slug : $category->term_id );

        $output .= "\t<option class=\"level-$depth\" data-filter-value=\".".$value."\"";
        if ( $value === (string) $args['selected'] ){ 
            $output .= ' selected="selected"';
        }
        $output .= '>';
        $output .= $pad.$cat_name;
        if ( $args['show_count'] )
            $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;('. $category->count .')';

        $output .= "</option>\n";
}
 }
```

Then I placed this code in my sidebar --

```
<?php

//first get the current term
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

//then set the args for wp_dropdown_categories
 $args = array(
    'walker'=> new SH_Walker_TaxonomyDropdown(),
    'value'=>'slug',
    'child_of' => $current_term->term_id,
    'taxonomy' => $current_term->taxonomy,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'depth'  => 2,
    'title_li' => '',
    'id' => 'filter-select',
    'class' => 'filter option-set',
        'show_option_all' => All,
        'hide_if_empty' => true
    );
 wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
?>
```