# Wordpress dropdown categories as radio fields

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make the default wp_dropdown_categories select dropdown as a radio input with submit button.

This is on the front end.

```
<form id="filter-select" class="filter-select" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
   <?php wp_dropdown_categories(); ?>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="view" />
</form>
```

Then in my functions.php I tried to do this

```php
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'dropdown_filter', 10, 2);

function dropdown_filter( $output, $r ) {
    $output = preg_replace( '/<option/i', '<input type="radio"', $output );

    $output = str_replace( 'class="level-0"', 'name="filter"', $output );
    $output = str_replace( "value=\"{$value}\"", "value=\"{$value}\" selected", $output );

    return $output;
}
```

This actually works in swapping out the select dropbox for a radio field. But it does not actually work correctly.

Instead of going to /category/CATEGORYNAME  - Like the default select box does.

It goes /?filter=6&submit=view

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: Okay thank you, not quite relevant to my problem but noted.

Comment: You can also control the output of the dropdown with a custom Walker. See the answer at the bottom of this thread, which you can tweak slightly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078572/how-to-change-value-for-options-and-select-in-wp-dropdown-categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a custom Walker to output category names instead of IDs.

```
<div class="radiobuttons">
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'hide_title_if_empty' => true,
  'title_li' => '',
  'walker' => new List_Categories_Radiobuttons
);
wp_list_categories( $args );
?>
</div>
```

The custom Walker in functions.php:

```
/**
 * Custom Walker to list categories with radio buttons
 */
class List_Categories_Radiobuttons extends Walker_Category {
  function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
    $category_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
    $radiobutton = '<input type="radio" name="filtercategory" value="' . $category_name . '">';
    $output .= '<div class="radiobutton">' . $radiobutton;
  }
  function end_el(&$output, $category, $depth=0, $args=array()) {
    $output .= "</div>\n";
  }
}
```

Does this point you in the right direction?

Comment: when I add walker to my functions.php it throws an error and doesn't let my website load.